# I need some help with finding out how to power LED's (And how "power" works in circuits in general)

Tags: voltage, led, current, resistance, watts

Ok, I am new to electronics, but I am getting a general idea. I need some questions answered to secure my knowledge:

1. If I have a device that consumes 5V and 600mA, will a source with more than 600mA work? If it does, explain to me how this works. Is it because the whole entire circuit just consumes the amount of current what it needs inherently?
2. How would the Voltage, Amperage, and Resistance work out if I had 2 LED strips in parallel, each taking 5V and 600mA? Please explain the math.
3. When making a circuit in general, what values need to balance out to make it stable? (Is it open and all you need to limit is voltage for components? What roles do amperage and resistance do to make a circuit work?)

I know I am asking the wrong things or have an incorrect knowledge, so please be patient with me and point me in the right direction. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Bare P-N junctions (such as LEDs) work slightly different from entire devices. They will pass as much current as they can get away with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A constant voltage power supply (the most common type) will deliver a fixed voltage at any current up to its rated maximum.  The actual current delivered will be determined by the load (assuming the load is designed to work from the supply's voltage).

If you have two LED strips in parallel, each requiring 5 volts at 600 mA, you would need a 5 volt power supply capable of delivering at least 1200 mA (1.2 Amp).

Comment: Thanks, this clears things up. So basically, any circuit will work with a constant voltage source if all components are either operating at that voltage or if resistance is added to certain parts or voltage is converted/regulated, and will draw a certain amount of current of all of the components calculated and added together?

Answer (score 0):

1) When someone says a device "can consume 5V and 600mA", they usually mean that is what the device is rated for. If the device is not a power supply (voltage source or current source), then it can usually be modeled as a resistive load (at least for DC circuits). So for your example, such a load could be modeled as an 8.333 Ohm resistor, such that if you connect a 5V source across the resistor, it will sink 600mA of current. Likewise, if you drive 600mA of current through the resistor, it will have a 5V drop across it.

The whole idea of how much voltage drops or current flows through a circuit is a result of Ohm's law. I suggest you familiarize yourself with this, and your understanding will become more clear.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law

2) This question is difficult, because LEDs do not act like traditional resistors. LEDs are diodes (Light-Emitting-Diode). You can think of a diode like a switch (at least an ideal diode in a DC circuit): If the voltage across the diode is greater than its "on voltage", then the diode turns on and allows current to pass through without resistance. I suggest the following reference for a better understanding of diodes or LEDs:
https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/diodes

3) I would need a bit more information about the kind of circuit you are trying to make, as there are many types of complicated circuits out there. Assuming you just mean simple DC circuits, I think you will find Ohm's law (linked in my answer to part 1) will describe how voltage, current, and resistance must always relate to each other.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Can you understand with pictures or graphs?

This is based on a 2V RED 3W power LEDs

Power sensitivity changes can be seen with supply voltage sweep from 0 to 5V.

Power and currents add in parallel.

[image]